# Manipulate an image mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

I'm having trouble making an image move left to right in mathematica.

I have the manipulate for a point,

```
(*Rook Movement*)
Manipulate[
  Graphics[Translate[Point[{0, 0}], {t, t2}], Axes -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 8}, {0, 8}}], {t, 0, 8}, {t2, 0, 8}]
```

I also have an image defined as "rook".

How do I replace the Point with my image of a rook?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "F16"}];
Manipulate[
 Graphics[Inset[img, {t, t2}], Axes -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 8}, {0, 8}}], {t, 0, 8}, {t2, 0, 8}]
```

[image]